# Android MediaPlayer Audio SeekBar

Tags: android, audio, media-player, mp3, seekbar

This sort of question seems to have come up a here a lot, but they are all a slightly different case to mine and have just confused me. I am trying to get my SeekBar to synchronise with a single and specified mp3. With the code below, the audio plays and if you move the SeekBar the audio DOES seek, however the SeekBar does not move on its own to update with the music. Could someone please see if they can find the problem that is stopping the SeekBar from updating?

FIXED NOW but don't know why it fixed.

This is my FIXED Java code. Changes in bold:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Button buttonPlayPause;
    ImageView Image;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Handler handler;

    private int stateMediaPlayer;
    private final int stateMP_NotStarter = 0;
    private final int stateMP_Playing = 1;
    private final int stateMP_Pausing = 2;
    private int mediaPos;
    private int mediaMax;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playerwere);

        Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);

        Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.wereim);

        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        buttonPlayPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playpause);

        buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(buttonPlayPauseOnClickListener);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarOnSeekChangeListener);

        initMediaPlayer();

        mediaPos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        mediaMax = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        seekBar.setMax(mediaMax); // Set the Maximum range of the
                                    // seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos);// set
                                    // current progress to song's
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos);// set current progress to song's

        handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);
        handler.postDelayed(moveSeekBarThread, 100);

    }

    private Runnable moveSeekBarThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                int mediaPos_new = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                int mediaMax_new = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

                seekBar.setMax(mediaMax_new);
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos_new);

                handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // Looping the thread after 0.1
                                                // seconds
            } **else {
                int mediaPos_new = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                int mediaMax_new = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

                seekBar.setMax(mediaMax_new);
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos_new);

                handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // Looping the thread after 0.1
                                                // seconds
            }**
        }
    };

    private void initMediaPlayer() {
        handler = new Handler();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(were.this, R.raw.were);
        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_NotStarter;  

    }

    Button.OnClickListener buttonPlayPauseOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (stateMediaPlayer) {
            case stateMP_NotStarter:
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause
                        .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Playing;
                break;
            case stateMP_Playing:
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayPause
                        .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Pausing;
                break;
            case stateMP_Pausing:
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause
                        .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Playing;
                break;
            }

        }
    };

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarOnSeekChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
            }

        }
    };


}
```

Comment: http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/an-android-seekbar-for-your-mediaplayer. the link might help

Comment: it would be helpful but i can't really see a significant difference between it and mine.

Comment: I've fixed it, see above.